# "[remote rejected master]" -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I use Window machine. I want to upload my web game to heroku but I get the following error:

```
        E:\node3>git push heroku master
    Counting objects: 754, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (687/687), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (754/754), 3.88 MiB | 313.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 754 (delta 220), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Node.js app detected
    remote:
    remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
    remote:
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
    remote:        NODE_ENV=production
    remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
    remote:
    remote: -----> Installing binaries
    remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
    remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
    remote:
    remote:        Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
    remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.11.1...
    remote:        Using default npm version: 3.8.6
    remote:
    remote: -----> Restoring cache
    remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
    remote:
    remote: -----> Building dependencies
    remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
    remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
    remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
    remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_396b33dc70a40199869b48acc6cc98f7/.herok
    u/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_396b33dc70a40199869b48acc6cc98f7/.heroku/node/bin/n
    pm" "rebuild"
    remote:        npm ERR! node v5.11.1
    remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
    remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_396b33dc70a40199869b48acc6cc98f7/node_mo
    dules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/cli.js
    remote:        npm ERR! code ENOENT
    remote:        npm ERR! errno -2
    remote:        npm ERR! syscall chmod
    remote:
    remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/bu
    ild_396b33dc70a40199869b48acc6cc98f7/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node
    _modules/mime/cli.js'
    remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/bu
    ild_396b33dc70a40199869b48acc6cc98f7/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node
    _modules/mime/cli.js'
    remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

    remote:        npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a fi
    le.
    remote:        npm ERR! enoent
    remote:
    remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support reque
    st:
    remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_396b33dc70a40199869b48acc6cc98f7/npm-debu
    g.log
    remote:
    remote: -----> Build failed
    remote:
    remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common is
    sues here:
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploy
    s
    remote:
    remote:        Some possible problems:
    remote:
    remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
    remote:        https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-fo
    lder-into-git
    remote:
    remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a
    -node-js-version
    remote:
    remote:        Love,
    remote:        Heroku
    remote:
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to iktsl.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/iktsl.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/iktsl.git'

    E:\node3>git push heroku master
    Counting objects: 754, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (687/687), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (754/754), 3.88 MiB | 322.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 754 (delta 220), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Node.js app detected
    remote:
    remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
    remote:
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
    remote:        NODE_ENV=production
    remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
    remote:
    remote: -----> Installing binaries
    remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
    remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
    remote:
    remote:        Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
    remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.11.1...
    remote:        Using default npm version: 3.8.6
    remote:
    remote: -----> Restoring cache
    remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
    remote:
    remote: -----> Building dependencies
    remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
    remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
    remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
    remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_373306132b00e684ff5b33e668925804/.herok
    u/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_373306132b00e684ff5b33e668925804/.heroku/node/bin/n
    pm" "rebuild"
    remote:        npm ERR! node v5.11.1
    remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
    remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_373306132b00e684ff5b33e668925804/node_mo
    dules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/cli.js
    remote:        npm ERR! code ENOENT
    remote:        npm ERR! errno -2
    remote:        npm ERR! syscall chmod
    remote:
    remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/bu
    ild_373306132b00e684ff5b33e668925804/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node
    _modules/mime/cli.js'
    remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/bu
    ild_373306132b00e684ff5b33e668925804/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node
    _modules/mime/cli.js'
    remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

    remote:        npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a fi
    le.
    remote:        npm ERR! enoent
    remote:
    remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support reque
    st:
    remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_373306132b00e684ff5b33e668925804/npm-debu
    g.log
    remote:
    remote: -----> Build failed
    remote:
    remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common is
    sues here:
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploy
    s
    remote:
    remote:        Some possible problems:
    remote:
    remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
    remote:        https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-fo
    lder-into-git
    remote:
    remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a
    -node-js-version
    remote:
    remote:        Love,
    remote:        Heroku
    remote:
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to iktsl.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/***.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I know it is somehow connected with node_modules, but I can't understand what's the matter.
I will be grateful for any help. Thanks.

My package.json

```
{
"name": "iktsl",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "4.x",
  "socket.io": "^1.3.5" 
  }
}
```

Comment: `node_modules checked into source control` Did you ignore the `node_modules` folder? Maybe you committed the `node_modules` directory into source control and then pushed it. If you did so, first remove the `node_modules` directory from the repository, then ignore it and push your app again

Comment: @AliDehghani, can you tell me please, how to ignore "node_modules"?

Comment: First use `git -r --cached -- node_modules` then commit the changes and push again

Comment: @AliDehghani, I get the following error: "Unknown option -r", when I use that command.

Comment: @AliDehghani thanks anyway! I deleted node_modules and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it work..have fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `node_modules` folder to `.gitignore`. To do this add this line in .gitignore file `node_modules/`.

The other solution is to simply delete the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: i dont know why (because in official doc say dont do this but ..)but this is solution of my problem

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue
The solution for this is

1. Delete the package-lock.json file on both the client and server
2. Make sure that you are using at least the LTS version of Node locally
3. Make sure your local Node version matches what is shown in the package.json file's engines property.
4. Run the git add . , git commit -m "fixing versions"  and git push heroku master commands to force a rebuild.

Comment: doesnt work unfortunately